# Does cache: 'no-store' in fetch make a component behave like it's client-side rendered in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working with Next.js and using the fetch method to retrieve data:

```js
const res = await fetch(`${process.env.url}/test`, {
  cache: 'no-store',
})
```

As I understand it, specifying `cache: 'no-store'` should force a new data fetch each time a user loads a page.

This has led me to question whether this option makes the component behave more like it's client-side rendered. Usually, when I execute `npm run build`, Next.js generates static HTML files after fetching data at build time.

However, using `cache: 'no-store'` appears to cause data to be fetched each time the page is loaded, not at build time. Does this mean that my component is essentially behaving as if it were client-side rendered? I would appreciate any clarification on this matter.

```js
async function fetchItems() {
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.url}/test`, {
    cache: 'no-store',
  })

  const items: Item[] = await res.json()
  return items
}

export const ItemList = async () => {
  const items = await fetchItems()
  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <li key={item.id}>
          {item.title}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: When used like in your example you are basically telling the component to replicate the behavior seen in `getServerSideProps` where the component will request the API each time if the request is not cached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add `cache: 'no-store'` as an option to [`fetch`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch), it means disabling [Static Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering#static-rendering) (generating HTML files at build time, caching them, and sending them when there is a request) and using [Dynamic Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering#dynamic-rendering) (generating HTML files after there is a request and sending them).

The component still fetchs data and renders on the server, so no, it's not like making a call client side in a `useEffect`, in which case, the part that depends on the fetched data will not be in the initial HTML the server sends.

Answer (score 1):

if it was behaving as if it were client-side rendered, you would not have `async` component.

```
async function fetchItems() {}
```

async component works only on server. `no-store` makes it like `getServerSideProps`. by default next.js caches fetched data, if you were fetching a user from the database, you would always get the initial user.